# c++ numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() for values other than 1

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

`numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` is defined to be the difference between 1.0 and the next value representable by double, but I want to find/calculate the `numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` of a value other than 1.0? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [`std::nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Maybe an answer in there? (Or maybe a dupe?)

Comment: The epsilon of any double value will be epsilon for 1.0 multiplied by the binary representation of the exponent of the double value.

Comment: Is it the scaled epsilon you want? Then have an example of an `almost_equal` function at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, you can use [`std::nextafter`](http://%60https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter):

> ```
> float       nextafter ( float from, float to );
> ```
>
> Returns the next representable value of from in the direction of to.

```
float f = /* ... */
float next_after_f = std::nextafter(f, std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
```